# Trigger on EmailMessage to capture when an email is opened

Tags: trigger, emailmessage

Is there a way to capture the opening of an email sent as an activty of the opportunity object for example? I wrote a trigger on EmailMessagge (after update) but is not invoked.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not currently a way to capture this. The updating of `EmailMessage.Status` from 0 (New) to 1 (Read) that occurs when a user opens the message does not fire triggers. You can vote to [change this on the IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000biKgAAI).

Comment: Based on release notes for that Idea, not clear if new functionality applies to email reads when related object is not a Case